# Django multiple database support

Tags: django

Using Django 1.4 is it possible to have 2 apps within the same project use two different databases?

If so, will each app have there own settings.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases) on how to define multiple databases in your settings.

To use a different database for each app you can use one of to approaches:

1. You can [manually select a database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database) on each database call. This will probably not be possible if you used third party apps.
2. You can [define a database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) which is probably more suitable if you do not want to modify an app. There is an [example in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example) which explains how to route reads/writes to another database.